# Angular JS - is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error in controller.js

controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']).controller('authCtl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "loginService", function($scope, $rootScope, loginService) {
  $rootScope.bodyClass = "focusedform";
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    loginService.userAuth($scope.username, $scope.password);
  }
}]);
```

factory.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('loginService', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
  userFactory = {};
  userAuth = function(username, password) {
    console.log(username + '' + password);
  };
  return true;
}]);
```

[image]

Comment: You're returning true from login service. Return an object or something with the userAuth function attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't return your object in factory.

You have to attach your methods variable in an object and return it from factory in order to access from controller.

Try like this

```
angular.module('warApp').factory('loginService', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
  var userFactory = {};
  userFactory.userAuth = function(username, password) {
    console.log(username + '' + password);
  };
  return userFactory;
}]);
```

or try like this for better view

```
angular.module('warApp').factory('loginService', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
  var userFactory = {
    userAuth: userAuth
  }
  return userFactory;
  function userAuth(username, password) {
    console.log(username + '' + password);
  }
}]);
```